# how to download html file in php

Tags: php, ms-word, http-headers, download

I'm creating a doc file with the php.

I'm using `echo` to output everything but I can see that my html is properly created in my response but the download is not starting.

How can I make this download to start?

Part of my code:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 
header("Content-type: application/msword; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=test.doc");

echo $main_html; //html code
```

Comment: http://us3.php.net/readfile take a look at the first example. Should help you

Comment: @mituw16 the file is dynamically created, I don't save anything on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this, and it works perfect.

```
file_put_contents("test.doc",$main_html);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: application/msword; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=test.doc");
readfile("test.doc");
unlink("test.doc");
die;
```

**Note :** if you may already know, header only works before passing any output to the browser, including line break and even a space .

Comment: I have the problem with the unlink method..my file is not getting deleted...any ideas?

Comment: the download is fine?
 are you crating it using php?

Comment: try `chmod($filename,777)`

Answer (score 0):

To start an download, you have to use the content-type `application/octet-stream` to start an download as mentioned in [RFC 2046](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt).

Btw. you have to echo the content of the doc file and not your html content(i.e. use `readfile('test.doc')` as mentioned in other answers or simply echo the content of your doc file)

Comment: what about the application/msword ? since I want to create a `doc` file

Comment: If you want to download the file(not display), you shouldn't use application/msword, or the browser plugin tries to display the word document

Comment: I was using this already but only with the GET method and everything was working as it should. Now I'm using ajax and POSt method to do the same thing and now I can't make the download to start

Comment: If you send your request with ajax, this doesn't work - you have to locate your browser (i.e. using `window.location`) to the php script, which offers the file download)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=read.html;"); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me.. I ran this on my server

```
<?php
$main_html = "<h1>Hey I'm Nate</h1>"; // I did put this in
header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 
header("Content-type: application/msword; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=test.doc");

echo $main_html; //html code
```

Did you define `$main_html` before echoing? Because all I changed was added some html to it.

It started a download right away, with the correct content in the document.

Comment: this is working if you go directly to the site. But I'm using ajax to send some variables to that php file